# Копирование массива с добавлением новой проперти

Tags: typescript

Делаю копию массива объектов,  через функцию map.
Почему не возникает ошибки при на новую проперть xxx, которая не объявлена в интерфейсе?

```
interface A{
  a:number;
  b:string;
};

let a:A[] = [{a:1, b:"a"}, {a:2, b:"b"}];

let b:A[] = a.map((x)=>({...x, xxx:"abc"}));
```

Comment: Потому что интерфейс описывает то что должно быть и ему неважно что есть что-то лишнее.

Answer (score 0):

У ответа 2 части.

**Часть Первая:**

Это пример ковариантности. TypeScript вывел тип:

```
{
    xxx: string;
    a: number;
    b: string;
}
```

Который является подтипом интерфейса `A`. То что можно сделать с супертипом, можно сделать и с подтипом. Ошибки тут нет, это правильное и ожидаемое поведение, как в других языках. За подробностями можно обратиться к термину "Вариантность" в программировании. К сожалению не могу дать одного источника со всеми разъяснениями, можно начать копать с книги "Профессиональный TypeScript" за авторством Черный Б.

**Часть Вторая:**

А дальше интереснее. Можно сделать так, чтобы нам выдавалась ошибка при использовании литерала объекта благодаря [этой фиче](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks).

Проще говоря, в случае прямого присваивания TypeScript проверяет состав полей и говорит нам о потенциальной ошибке. Тоже относится к прямому возврату литерала объекта через return или пишем тот же литерал при вызове функции.

Тут мы немного подсказываем компилятору что у нас тип является интерфейсом `А`:

```
// Ошибка!
let b: A[] = a.map((x): A =>({ ...x, xxx: "abc" }));

// Тоже ошибка!
const doIt = (s: A) => null;
doIt({ ...a[0], xxx: "abc" });

// Ещё одна ошибка!
let e: A = { ...a[0], xxx: "abc" };
```

Но это работает только на одном уровне присваивания, дальше включается ковариантность:

```
// Нет ошибки
let c: A[] = a.map((x): A => {
    const some = { ...x, xxx: "abc" };
    const other: A = some;
    return other;
});
```

[Ссылка на песочницу](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=false#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQzlwBcyIArgLYBG0A3LvpcQM5hSgDmdOAvl7rgBsIYAsVQBtALrIAvMnEZRyAIwAaZI2QAiOFuTd1iosgBM6zVsp7ukvjiEjNE6XLgA6cnAAOACh8APAEpZAD4fRTdI-3V-WOIdSgRrQMC7B2QEMSlZAg9vPyCxUMx6fAyAexAWZCZy8hQ5CKiYuO04ROsuMoqqkXKwAAtoIrla+q6yqGFSKBBkfqGoLm5U-nthZAATLJdcz18AwJGwprdo5Fj-ePak-RS0jYgRzGRItzhxAAZJFqu2jv0DxEMGefmCMhCyHCr0iH2+v2uAJWgR8qxwawQlWqm3KAEkRHIfEwxODIWQBAI7Dj8dC3nCfhdWglbisaEA)